# Using grep to get lines from a file (.tsv) that contain specific samples listed in a sample file (.tsv)

Tags: linux, cancer, filtering, awk, grep

So I have a file, let's call it pcawg.tsv. It's formatted like the one down below.

```
Tumor sample ID  Normal sample ID  Mechanism
a                1                 deletion
b                2                 ecDNA
c                3                 ecDNA
```

I have a file of tumor sample ID's with the ecDNA mechanism called ecDNA_samples.tsv. It's formatted like this:

```
Tumor sample ID
a
b
```

To filter and extract the lines of `pcawg.tsv` that contain the tumor sample ID's in `ecDNA_samples.tsv` into a new file, I used this line of code below.

```
grep -f ecDNA_samples.tsv pcawg.tsv > ecDNA.vcf.tsv
```

Would this be the right code to use?

Comment: This has been asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110645/select-lines-from-text-file-which-have-ids-listed-in-another-file

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use `grep` to do this? It would be possible to make a more robust solution using R.

Comment: I kind of have to use this with Linux because I'm working with a Linux-based secure computing portal, since we have patient data which is confidential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```
cat ecDNA_samples.tsv | xargs -I % grep '^%\s' pcawg.tsv
```

The command above executes `grep '^<line>\s' pcawg.tsv`, for each line of ecDNA_samples.tsv. Which matches the lines taken from ecDNA_samples.tsv to the sequences of characters between line start and a white-space in pcawg.tsv.

Comment: So I ran this code as cat ecDNA_samples.tsv | xargs -I % grep '^%\s' pcawg.tsv>ecDNA_normal.tsv, but when I opened the file ecDNA_normal.tsv in my directory, the file was empty.

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>` so an empty result at the end doesn't end up as the result instead of *everything* you've captured.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Comment: @RamRS It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case an R solution is acceptable as well, this should be fairly robust code because it properly parses the TSV files and matches up column names:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(tidyverse)
read_tsv("pcawg.tsv") %>%
   inner_join(read_tsv("ecDNA_samples.tsv")) %>%
   write_tsv("filtered_pcawg.tsv")
```